# How to enable a GitHub repo with partial clones capability?

Tags: git, github

I referenced [this article](https://github.blog/2020-01-17-bring-your-monorepo-down-to-size-with-sparse-checkout/) that demonstrate the new feature exists in Git 2.25 called `partial clones`. I followed the tutorial they provided, and it works.

```
$ git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout https://github.com/derrickstolee/sparse-checkout-example
Cloning into 'sparse-checkout-example'...
Receiving objects: 100% (373/373), 75.98 KiB | 2.71 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (23/23), done.

$ cd sparse-checkout-example/

$ git sparse-checkout init --cone
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), 1.41 KiB | 1.41 MiB/s, done.

$ git sparse-checkout set client/android
Receiving objects: 100% (26/26), 985.91 KiB | 5.76 MiB/s, done.
```

When I change another repo to clone (see below), it just doesn't works. It still fetched all the objects from the repo.

```
$ git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout https://github.com/angular/angular-cli
Cloning into 'angular-cli'...
warning: filtering not recognized by server, ignoring
remote: Enumerating objects: 48, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (48/48), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (41/41), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (84440/84440), 35.93 MiB | 2.92 MiB/s, done.92 eceiving objects: 100% (84440/84440), 35.89 MiB | 2.95 MiB/s       
Resolving deltas: 100% (53794/53794), done.
```

It said `warning: filtering not recognized by server, ignoring`. I also tried many of my repos. It still not working. I can't figure out how to enable a repo that can do the partial clone from a git client v2.25+. How can I enable a repo on GitHub for this purpose?

Comment: Most likely GitHub doesn't support it (yet). Is your repository very large? Unless your repo is many gigabytes in size, you don't ever need to even think about sparse checkouts or partial clones.

Comment: @mvp We have some mono repo have large amount of files and thousands of commits. That's why I consider sparse checkouts and partial clones.

Comment: Just tried the command for angular-cli and got no warning. GitHub must have enabled the partial-clone feature more generally since you tried :)